# Align Search Box and Search Button horizontally with the Navigation Links in HTML5

Tags: html, css

How do I align horizontally the search box and button with the navigation links in HTML5? I have added the search box to the navigation bar but it rests below the navigation links.

Below is a picture of the problem:

[image: The search box located at the buttom]

```css
/* Below is the code for the navigation bar */

nav {           
    display: block;
} 

nav {
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    widht: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #68b12f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    border: 2px solid #509111;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5b992b;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    widht: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #68b12f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    border: 2px solid #509111;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5b992b;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Below is the code for the search box and button */

#search-bar {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#search-button {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Below is the code for the navigation bar. -->

<div class="navigation" id="navigation">   
  <nav>
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/data_centre/register.php">Booking</a></li> 
      <li><a href="/data_centre/display_user.php">Display User</a></li> 
      <form>
        <input name="q" id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search">
        <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
      </form>
    
    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

I just want to align the navigation links and search box and find button horizontally.

Comment: I used the float property but it placed the search button behind the search box. But I want the search box to be behind the search button i.e.                 --search box-- --search /find button--     but the float places them this way         --search/find button-- --search box--

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kqhoy3av/?

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy your suggestion worked.

Comment: I think its better to create a table with no border and place elements inside cell's

Answer (score 0):

First of all please remove the

```
<form>
  <input name="q" id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search">
  <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

from the ul tag and wrap it in another div.

Refer this fiddle for brief: https://jsfiddle.net/nirmohi_shah/50aL2vhy/3/

Answer (score -1):

A form should not go inside an ul for this case, remove it from there and take it out to align horizontally:

HTML

```
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">   
    <nav>
        <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/data_centre/register.php">Booking</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/data_centre/display_user.php">Display User</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="searchbar">
        <form>
            <input name="q" id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search">
            <input id="search-button" type="submit" value="Find">
        </form>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.searchbar {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0;
}
ul#navigation {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you copied my answer from the fiddle I attached in my answer. @JMF